# Mootools - How to append text at the beginning 

Tags: javascript, mootools

How to append text at the begin using function appendText?

For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="myElement">Hey.</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('myElement').appendText('Howdy. ', 'before');
```

Expected result: Howdy. Hey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element) I believe you can achieve it using the following:

```
$('myElement').appendText(' Howdy. ','top');
```

which produces [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vPzJF/)

Using `'before'` will append the first param immediately before the `<div />` tags:

```
<body>
   Howdy. <div id="myElement">Hey.</div>
</body>
```

Using `'top'` will append the first param immediately after the opening `<div>` tag:

```
<body>
  <div id="myElement"> Howdy. Hey.</div>
</body>
```